# Selenium - Google Travel Scraping Price History missing

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-chromedriver, selenium-firefoxdriver

I am returning html with this python script but it doesn't return price history (see screenshot). Using non-selenium browser does return html with the prices (even without expending this section by simple regex); chrome/safari/firefox all do, incognito as well.

[image]

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time

url = 'https://www.google.com/flights?hl=en#flt=SFO.JFK.2021-06-01*JFK.SFO.2021-06-07'

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()

driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
driver.get(url)
time.sleep(10)
html = driver.page_source
print(html)

driver.quit()
```

I can't quite pinpoint if it's some setting in chromedriver. It is possible to do because there is a 3rd party scraper that currently returns this data.

Tried this to no avail. [Can a website detect when you are using Selenium with chromedriver?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33225947/can-a-website-detect-when-you-are-using-selenium-with-chromedriver)

Any thoughts appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After I added `chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled")` I started to see this block. Not sure why it is not always loaded.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait

from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

url = 'https://www.google.com/flights?hl=en#flt=SFO.JFK.2021-06-01*JFK.SFO.2021-06-07'
chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("start-maximized")
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='/snap/bin/chromium.chromedriver', chrome_options=chrome_options)
driver.get(url)
# wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
# wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".EA71Tc.q7Eewe")))
time.sleep(10)
history = driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".EA71Tc.q7Eewe").get_attribute("innerHTML")
print(history)
```

Here the full block is returned, including all tag names. As you see, I tried explicit waits, but this block was not visible. Experiment with adding another explicit wait.

Comment: Thanks, any ideas on how to return it in headless mode, it does not currently, only with GUI.